# Swift 2 if case syntax with enum having associated values

Tags: swift, syntax, enums, swift2, pattern-matching

I'm stuck with some really simple syntax I guess, but I can't find how to solve it.

- First of all here's the setup, let me introduce a nice enum with multiple associated values

  ```
  enum Entity {
      case City(data: CityData, position: NSRange)
      case Date(date: NSDate)
      case Service
  }
  ```
- Then I would like to check if a field of some dictionary is a city and if it is, deal with its data and position... The only way I could manage is *via* a `switch`!!!

  ```
  if let city = result["ABC"] {
      switch city {
      case .City(data:let data, position:let position): // Do something with data and position
      default: // Do nothing
      }
  }
  ```

And I was wondering if the `if case`syntax could be of any help...

But I could not find it (may be the tiredness, I hope...)

I'm looking for something like that:

```
if case result["ABC"] == .City(data:let data, position:let position) { 
    // Do something with data and position
}
```

So I'm sure it's obvious, but I've missed it... So if you can help, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Swift dictionaries return optional values. So, using `switch`, you should do:

```
switch result["ABC"] {
case let .City(data, position)?:
   // Do something with data and position
default:
  break
}
```

Using `if` pattern matching:

```
if case let .City(data, position)? = results["ABC"] {
  // Do something with data and position
}
```

Comment: Woot! Great! Many thanks. I knew it was simple, but I was struggling with this and I didn't manage to find out the way. Anyway, thanks again Wallace!